# Create posts using xml files and images

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, image

I am writing a simple plugin that should take exported from indesign XML files, and image files - and create post drafts from it.

I have 2 inputs. One for xml files, and one for all images:

```
   <input type="file" name="xmlupload1[]" id="xmlupload[]" multiple="">
   <input type="file" name="imgsupload1[]" id="imgsupload[]" multiple="">
```

Inside XML there is post's content and img tags of images that relevant to this post, looks like this:

```
   <img href="1_ChrisGardner.jpg" caption="credit: wikipedia"></img>
```

I want to upload the images just like wordpress was do it, add the relevant caption from "caption" attribute to each image, and attach it to parent post.

I did many manipulations with $_FILES array and wordpress upload functions with no success...

Some of php code:

```
$XMLfiles = $_FILES['xmlupload']['tmp_name'];
$post_imgs = $_FILES['imgsupload'];

    foreach ($XMLfiles as $xmlfile){ {

    //CREATE POST FROM XML:

    $xmlstring = file_get_contents($xmlfile);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);

    $content = '';
    $title = $xml->xpath('//h1');
    $post_title = $title[0];

    $excerpt = $xml->xpath('//h2');
    $post_excerpt = $excerpt[0];

    $author = $xml->xpath('//author');
    $post_author = end($author);

    $post_id = create_post($post_title, $post_excerpt);

    $imagetags = $xml->xpath('//img');
    $img_captions = array();
    foreach($imagetags as $imagetag) {
        $img_caption = '';
        $atts = $imagetag->attributes();
        $img_fname = end(explode('/', $image['href']));
        $img_caption = $atts['caption']; 
        $img_captions[$img_fname] = $img_caption;
            unset($imagetag);
    }       

    $paragraphs = $xml->xpath('//p');
    foreach($paragraphs as $p){
        $p->addAttribute('class', 'p1');
    }

    $stories = $xml->xpath('//Story');
    foreach($stories as $story) {
        $content = $content.str_replace( '
        <Story>', '', str_replace( '</Story>', '', $story->asXML()));
    }

    update_post($post_id, $post_title, $post_excerpt, $content, $post_author, $issue_number);

    //ATTACH UPLOADED IMAGES TO POST:
    foreach ($post_imgs['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($post_imgs['name'][$key]) {
            $file = array(
            'name'     => $post_imgs['name'][$key],
            'type'     => $post_imgs['type'][$key],
            'tmp_name' => $post_imgs['tmp_name'][$key],
            'error'    => $post_imgs['error'][$key],
            'size'     => $post_imgs['size'][$key]
            );
            $img_caption = $img_captions[urlencode($file['name'])];
            $new_file = wp_handle_upload($file, array( 'test_form' => false ));

            $filename = $new_file['url'];
            $parent_post_id = $post_id;
            $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );
            $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

            // Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
            $attachment = array(
            'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ), 
            'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
            'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
            'post_content'   => '',
            'post_status'    => 'inherit',
            'post_excerpt' => $img_caption
            );

            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
            $img_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id );
            $img_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $img_id, $filename );

            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $img_id, $img_data );
        }
    }
}
```

It seems it doesn't work properly and also do not create additional image sizes...

Please, help!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what error you got ? did the posts created?

Comment: Now, I see that the image sizes are not generated, should I use another function to do it?

When I'am trying to do it from plugin Regenerate Image sizes - I get error.
The originally uploaded image file cannot be found at /local/home/....wp-content/uploads/http://..../wp-content/uploads/2015/06/web_1_MainPic_4.jpg